# A Nickel that can't be picked up

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth, the-binding-of-isaac-afterbirth

I've played several runs in these days, and I've encountered twice a strange **Nickel**

[image]
that I can't pick up.

I thought it was a bug, but two clues make an evidence.

It has nothing different from a normal Nickel (maybe it's a bit lighter), I hear the sound of a dropped coin when I touch it, and I can't understand what's its purpose.

Has anyone else found it? Any idea?

Comment: I'm assuming your money counter isn't full?

Comment: There are a few special kinds of coins that appear as Trinkets, but as far as I'm aware, none of them make coin sounds when you touch them... they make the usual Trinket pickup sound/animation.

Comment: Looks like the Burnt Penny trinket. Are you sure you aren't doing a challenge which locks you into certain trinkets? And are you sure you didn't accidentally pick up The Tick? It prevents you from picking up other trinkets.

Comment: I had the same problem in the daily run with eve (I think it was 2 days ago). I am guessing it is a bug, so better go and report it somewhere :)

Comment: @HugoZink it's definitely not a trinket. Had the same drop myself, without having any trinket equipped, and I wasn't able to pick it up. We still cannot rule out the possibility that it's a bug, but since there's still a lot of secrets to discover in the DLC it's worth investigating further

Comment: @Kappei got it, it's not a trinket (I can recognize the Burnt Penny) and my money counter was 33. Anyway you can still pick up coins even if you have 99 of them. I've found it in the yesterday daily run, in Depths.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purpose is still unclear, but it looks like it can be picked up [if you bomb it](https://www.reddit.com/r/bindingofisaac/comments/3r7bmy/did_anybody_also_come_accross_special_nickels/cwlijzn).

This could mean two things:

- the Nickel is glitchy and bombing it somehow resets its status, allowing you to pick it up, OR
- the Nickel is connected to the Greed theme of the DLC. After all, using a bomb, worth 5 cents in the store, to get 5 cents from the floor means you value more the money than the items. Or maybe I'm reading too much into this.

McMillen and Tyrone Rodriguez have heavily hinted at secrets still undiscovered in the DLC, so this hard-to-pick Nickel may be tied to something else, at the moment still unknown.

Comment: I'll try to update the answer if something new comes out in the future.

Comment: I don't think it's a glitch or a bug, because I've found other normal Nickels, probably it's just another kind of penny (like the Lucky Penny) which is hard to recognize from the original. Anyway, thank you for your suggestion!

Answer (score 4):

The last update explained that this kind of nickel is called [**Sticky Nickel**](http://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/Coins#Sticky_Nickels):

> A Nickel that will flip upside-down when Isaac tries to collect it. Afterwards, it will get stuck on the ground, unable to be picked up unless blasted off the ground with an explosion.

It can be now unlocked by completing [Boss Rush](http://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/Boss_Rush) with

> [Keeper](http://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/Keeper)

Comment: It sounds like these nickels are actually a bad thing, since you have to waste a bomb to pick them up. However, they are actually a benefit - if you don't have Sticky Nickels unlocked, they will be regular pennies instead (worth only 1 cent). So yes, you're "spending" a bomb to collect the nickel, but you're also getting more money than you normally would have.

Comment: @MageXy it was probably a bug, but I've found it before even unlocking Sticky Nickels and The Keeper.